Console Log Error While Exporting Godot Project To .AAB
CONSOLE LOG ERROR SCREENSHOT Godot Console Log Error While Exporting To .AAB File Format
I got this error while exporting godot project to .AAB
editor/export/editor_export_platform.h:182 - Export: Unable to copy and rename export file:

Configure project :
WARNING: The option setting 'android.overridePathCheck=true' is experimental.
The current default is 'false'.


Task :copyAndRenameDebugAab FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':copyAndRenameDebugAab'.


Cannot access a file in the destination directory. Copying to a directory which contains unreadable content is not supported. Declare the task as untracked by using Task.doNotTrackState(). For more information, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/incremental_build.html#disable-state-tracking in the Gradle documentation.
> Failed to create MD5 hash for file content.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 25s
1 actionable task: 1 executed

How does this question relate to the Java Programing Language>

use [code block] format for the log output to make it readable.ç

Task copyAndRenameReleaseAab depends on an AAB file to copy and rename. Therefore one can assume, that the build already fails previously and that there is no such file; it's sloppy programming, not to check for the existence of a file.

What to do guys?

maybe you should check and consider the question and its answer: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?
